# How can an get count of the unique lengths of a string in database rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle and I have a table with 1000 rows.  There is a last name field and

I want to know the lengths of the name field but I don't want it for every row.  I want a count of the various lengths.

Example:

lastname:

```
smith
smith
Johnson
Johnson
Jackson
Baggins
```

There are two smiths length of five.  Four others, length of seven.  I want my query to return

```
7
5
```

If there were 1,000 names I expect to get all kinds of lengths.

I tried,

```
Select count(*) as total, lastname from myNames group by total
```

It didn't know what total was.  Grouping by lastname just groups on each individual name unless it's a different last name, which is as expected but not what I need.

Can this be done in one SQL query?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the different lengths and their count, like `7|4 5|2`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT Length(lastname)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Length(lastname)
```

Comment: I think he wants the number of lastnames that have the same length, so maybe add a `count(*)` field to the query.

Comment: This did not work (but thank you.)  It only game me 1000 for the count and then one length, a single returned row.  I know I have all kinds of lengths in there.

Comment: sigh.  dumb me.  I had to use trim around it or I got back all the records the same.

Comment: MS SQL Server has LEN() and  DATALENGTH() functions

Answer (score 7):

```
select distinct(LENGTH(lastname)) from mynames;
```

Comment: it only returned one row.  maybe I need to check my data again.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select count(*), Length(column_name) from table_name group by Length(column_name);
```

This will work for the different lengths in a single column.

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you want (for Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle syntax will be similar).

```
select len(ColumnName) as [Len(ColumnName)],
count(*) as [Count]
from [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
group by len(ColumnName)
order by len(ColumnName)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't think [Microsoft] SQL Server syntax will help for a question tagged [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info). It appears to me that you are asking the OP to figure out for himself how to translate your answer to Oracle syntax. I think you could have made the effort to translate the syntax yourself.